# AirflowException: SSH operator error: No authentication methods available

Tags: airflow

I've been using Apache Airflow for a while now and due to a use-case I need to re-write the SparkSubmitOperator to SSHOperator. My airflow is installed on AWS EMR and the spark-submit needs to happen on the same EMR. But the operator fails with - *AirflowException: SSH operator error: No authentication methods available*

I'm using the default *ssh_conn_id=ssh_default* and tried passing as *ssh_hook* as well, but nothing seems to work

dag-file

```
hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id='ssh_default')

spark_submit = """
spark-submit ....
"""

process = SSHOperator(
        task_id='execute_pySpark',
        ssh_hook=hook,
        command=spark_submit,
        do_xcom_push=True
    )
```

airflow connection

```
Conn Id:   ssh_default
Conn Type: SSH
Host:      localhost
```

Any insight is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -2):

Configure your SSH Connection as per the details specified at https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.2/howto/manage-connections.html?highlight=SSHOperator#ssh

Add the `username` and `password` if there is one. The `Host` field should contain the IP address of your remote VM unless your Spark Master is on localhost.